# Parsing yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss date time string?

Tags: c++

I have a date time that comes from mysql. I need to extract each part:

```
int year;
int month;
int day;
int hour;
int min;
int sec;
```

example:

```
2014-06-10 20:05:57
```

Is there a simpler way than running it through stringstream for each component? (no boost or c++11 solutions please).

Thanks

Comment: Note that you almost certainly want to parse "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss".

Comment: Dang your last sentence. I was like "`std::get_time`! `std::get_time`! `std::get_time`! Aww crap!"

Comment: No, I'm asking how to do it in C++ given the std string date time

Comment: Well, not quite `std::get_time` is [`std::time_get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get), available pre-C++11.

Comment: If it works on c++98 it is an option, I've never head of fscanf

Comment: @Milo What would January 1, 2014 at 9:00am look like as it comes from your database?  "2014-01-01 09:00:00"?  If so, your fields are fixed width, which will facilitate plain old index-based string manipulations.

Comment: Then `substr` could be useful, much as I hate to suggest implementing yet another quick-and-dirty date parser.  ...but fixed width... why not?  Year is at positions 0-3, month at 5-6, day at 8-9, hour at 11-12, minute at 14-15, and second at 17-18.

Comment: Whatever you implement, just wrap it in a subroutine call so that it's easy to change the internal implementation if you later decide to do something more forgiving/robust.  Implement the simple solution, set up a few unit / regression tests, and move on.

Comment: I don't understand why `sscanf` is not option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) is probably the most straightforward option. It is a C library function, so purists might disapprove it.

Here is an example:

```
int year;
int month;
int day;
int hour;
int min;
int sec;

const char * str = "2014-06-10 20:05:57";

if (sscanf(str, "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &min, &sec) == 6)
{
    // sscanf() returns the number of elements scanned, so 6 means the string had all 6 elements.
    // Else it was probably malformed.
}
```

[And here is a live test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0da7e504822b205e).

Another nice solution would also be to use a [C++11 regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) which would make for a more robust parsing of the string.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yeah but if the OP wanted to handle lots of formats i am sure he would consider c++11 or any of the boost functions that can help with this.

Comment: I guess the point is you can have robust, or you can have simple and dependency-free.  This is a case where simple and dependency free has been requested.

Comment: Agreed, for a flexible solution, he should go for a RegExp.

Comment: @glampert But then he would "have two problems." ;)