# C++ get dates between two dates

Tags: c++, sorting, date-range

I put every date in a vector of struct `(vector<value>)` :

```
struct value {
    string code;
    string date;
    string name;
};
```

The format of the dates is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

I want to get dates between two given dates (for example from 01/01/2016 to 01/02/2016). How i can do that?

Comment: nice video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo)  code [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/date.h)

Comment: if you used "YYYY/MM/DD" format you would be able to sort alphabetically by `date` field (w/o parsing it) and use `std::lower_bound` twice to get required range.

Comment: It depends on what form you need results in, but I'd use `copy_if` with a lambda (functor pre-11).

Comment: I noticed your somewhat new to SO, If one of the answers here has solved your issue, don't forget to accept the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This problem is twofold:**

1. How do you get sortable date values from string representations
2. How can you effectively sort said values.

**Finding valid timestamps from a date-string**

C++ uses the time_t object as a valid number of seconds from a set date (Jan 1, 1970 UTC) [There's plenty of concise information about that](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/), in every-case you may consider this an Integer-representation of time in seconds.

Next you need to know how to parse your data into a time-stamp: here are some rather some helpful links.

My preferred method is [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) - there's an example of that [Here on stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321793/date-time-conversion-string-representation-to-time-t). Also it [seems someone else has done the same course as you ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956444/c-using-scanf-or-any-other-function-to-get-date-mm-dd-yyyy-in-int)

You might want to consider using [A function of your own design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765014/convert-string-from-date-into-a-time-t), if the date format is unusual. In this case, using [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) is often the simplest way - the interface of this function is somewhat old-school "c-style", but that doesn't change the simple fact it works, and well.
[Here's a link to someone reading a simple-date with scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071342/reading-a-date-with-sscanf).

Turns out the code I wrote below is close to [The answer to this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153097/parsing-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-date-time-string)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>  
time_t GetDateFromObject(value & Date_Object)
{
    char * Date_String = Date_Object.date.c_str();
    int year, month, day, hour, minute, second;
    if(sscanf(Date_String , "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second) == 6)
    { 
        time_t rawTime;
        time(&rawTime);
        struct tm * parsedTime;
        parsedTime = localtime(&rawTime);

        // tm_year is years since 1900
        parsedTime->tm_year = year - 1900;
        // tm_months is months since january
        parsedTime->tm_mon = month - 1;
        parsedTime->tm_mday = day;
        parsedTime->tm_hour = hour;
        parsedTime->tm_min = minute;
        parsedTime->tm_sec = second;
        return mktime(parsedTime);
   }
}
```

**Association and sorting of dates**

Once you know how to get a time_t from your date, you can start creating an associative array of the data - in this case I'll be using a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

With that, here's an example of using a map to insert, sort, and output the data.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<ctime>

struct value {
    std::string code;
    std::string date;
    std::string name;
};

void Print_Range(std::vector<value> & Data, value & Date_Start, value & Date_end)
{
    std::map<time_t, value *> Associated_Data;
    for(auto Date_Object : Array_Of_Dates)
    {
        time_t Object_Time = GetDateFromObject(Date_Object);
        Associated_Data.insert(std::make_pair(Object_Time, & Date_Object); 
    }
    //as the std::map is sorted by-default, 
    //we can know locate the iterator for any two time codes
    time_t Search_From = GetDateFromObject(Date_Start);
    time_t Search_To = GetDateFromObject(Date_End);
    auto Start_IT = Associated_Data.find(Search_From);
    auto End_IT = Associated_Data.find(Search_To);

    std::cout << "Printing all dates in range \n";
    for(auto IT=Start_IT; IT != End_IT; IT++)
    {
        std::cout << IT->Second->date << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I use C++11 syntax here, if you don't understand [Range based loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) you might want to read up on them.
2. I'm assuming the structure you described is stored in a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector).
3. The "GetDateFromObject" function I'm using here is a placeholder for whatever function you use to get the timestamp)
4. [Inserting data into a map using std::make_pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286670/preferred-idiomatic-way-to-insert-into-a-map).
5. I'm holding pointers to the original value-objects.

Comment: the fomat of my date is " YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS" it simplifies something?

Comment: Very much so, you can use scanf, for this exact issue - If you update your question with the format, I'll see about updating my answer ;)

Comment: And after a little tinkering - I think that should do it :)

Answer (score 2):

The date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is special in that a lexicographic (letter by letter) comparison is the same as a time comparison, so you can just use that.

If your container isn't initially sorted by date, you'll have to go through all the dates one by one. `std::copy_if` provides a nice way of doing this:

```
std::vector<value> get_between(const std::vector<value>& v,
        const std::string& from, const std::string& to)
{
    std::vector<value> u;
    std::copy_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(u, u.begin()),
    [from,to](const auto& val) {
        return val.date >= from && val.date <= to;
    });
    return u;
}
```

`copy_if` looks through `[v.begin(), v.end()[` and plonks the elements into `u` from `u.begin()` onwards whenever the lambda returns true. They'll be in the same order as you gave them in.

If your range is sorted, you can use `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` to get the start and end iterators instead:

```
std::vector<value> get_between(const std::vector<value>& v,
        const std::string& from, const std::string& to)
{
    value fromv { "", from, "" };
    auto begin = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), fromv,
    [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return lhs.date < rhs.date;
    });

    value tov { "", to, "" };
    auto end = std::upper_bound(begin, v.end(), tov,
    [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
        return lhs.date < rhs.date;
    });

    return std::vector<value>(begin, end);
}
```

`lower_bound` and `upper_bound` find the first value of *at least* `from` and the first value of *more than* `to`, so that the range `[lb, ub[` is the range with values `[from, to]`.

Comment: yes the range is sorted .You can explain how to use the lower_bound and upper_bound ? maybe with code :) Thank you!

Comment: That's a really smart-solution, something to go into my code-snippets for sure!

Answer (score 1):

In example you could do like that: convert all dates to `time_t` value (numberical representation of the date and time) and then iterate through your vector and use normal comparation between three time_t numbers. For reference: `man mktime`, `man strptime`.

Comment: I am starting hating the anonimous downvoters demotivating helping other people :(.

Comment: I agree about said down-votes, you have my up-vote for trying to help.
That said, I imagine your down votes came from - 
You didn't present any code (even to convert the date values)
You referenced Man (Remember that most windows users don't know what man is, nor do they like using it when they do.)